# how to check if post is performed using cURL

Tags: forms, validation, curl, security

Simple question: How to detect if the form data posted to my site is done through cURL and not through the site's form page.

(Ex) user runs **curl -H"Host: http://mysite"  POST "post data" http://mysite** for any form in the site.

Since it is possible to set Referer and User Agent, i believe that they don't qualify as filtering criteria. Any suggestions or solutions are welcome.

Thanks & Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a token to your form that you generate dynamically and store it in the users session.  When the user submits a form check that the token from the form matches the token that's in the session.  This token should change every time the form is rendered. This will allow the form to be submitted only one time.

If the user submits a form with a stale token, just have them repost the form again with an error messages saying the form was stale and they need to repeat the operation again.

Curl can emulate a browser so nothing is going to be 100% effective, but this covers most of the cases.

You could also have this token field filled by JavaScript since curl doesn't execute it.

Comment: kudos...but in case if its a form that any anonymous user can enter or a registration form don't think i'll be of luck..and a human recognition approach like CAPTCHA is not an ideal one for me as i can't make the decision or even suggest to add one...

Comment: Sessions work just fine with anonymous users, you don't have to authenticate them for this approach to work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one would need to check to see if the form submit button was triggered.

Comment: good one...but i could set-off a false alarm by disabling the javascript and filling in the form won't i?

Comment: If one is using Javascript to check the form then yes. One could also have the form submit button append "&clicked=true" to the form post data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your security concern is, as you don't tell us. As far as the web server is concerned, cURL is effectively just another web browser; it just happens to be one that is controlled by command-line arguments and not a mouse.

Maybe you are concerned about protecting yourself from [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) and should look at the [OWASP CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: sorry about my question being abstract..thing is there's a friend of mine is working in spring mvc and this issue was raised saying it was possible to looping the curl hit and flooding the DB for registration page....i'd never thought about it and it might be possible in my PHP code...so felt the curiosity to ask about it..

Comment: Flood / DoS protection is an entirely different concept to client-detection. Theorectically any client can attempt to DoS you. Detecting cURL won't help you a great deal here. Maybe look at something like apache httpd-guardian (or similar for your chosen web server) that will block addresses making too many requests within a certain timeframe http://apache-tools.cvs.sourceforge.net/apache-tools/

Comment: true...but in my case it was a bit too specific...maybe its time to close this question its getting very ambiguous....thanks everyone for the answers and providing deep insight on this and hope this thread helps/educates someone else as much as it did to me..